# the Words 'Diffusion Model'

Tags: partial-differential-equations, stochastic-processes, brownian-motion, stochastic-differential-equations

In ; Stochastic's, SDE, PDE,  I have heard the terminology $\textit{"Diffusion Model" or "Diffusion Equation"}$.

The heat equation is sometimes also called the Diffusion Equation ( since it represents the diffusion of heat over some domain, or since its built from Brownian Motion which describes the random trajectories of a brownian particle ). I assume this is just lazy and the heat equation is just a 'very particular diffusion equation'.

Can anyone explain   what someone is referring to when they talk about $\textit{'a Diffusion Equation, or the Diffusion Part of the Equation'}$. If anyone can explain this from a mathematical or physical perspective that would be amazing.

Note see [Relationship between the diffusion equation and the heat equation](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1009897/relationship-between-the-diffusion-equation-and-the-heat-equation) for a closely related discussion.

Comment: It's mostly just a naming convention. You get a construction kit for interesting equations in $u_t=cu_x+du_{xx}+f(u)$ where $cu_x$ is a transport term after the transport equation $u_t=cu_x$, $du_{xx}$ the diffusion term for its connection to the Brownian motion and heat equation, as you said, and a local reaction term $f(u)$ for birth-death dynamics, or chemical reaction equations etc.

Comment: Historic names.. related to its first application...